# can't access my website from local network

Tags: centos, web-server

I have a problem with my web server or my local network, I don't know exactly.

I have centos 6 running as web server, and it was configured using webmin.

Now I can browse my website from anywhere, but when I am in the office, I mean when I am in the same LAN with the web server, I can't browse it. I tried to ping it and my machine can see the web server, I have also checked SELinux, it was disabled.

This problem started since I created a new windows domain and moved all desktops and windows servers to it. Before, the web server was working fine from inside and outside office.

Answer (score 2):

You either have an issue with DNS or nat loopback.

NAT loopback/hairpin/several other names is what lets you access something on the same LAN using the public IP address.  Is is a configuration in your router.

Before you probably had DNS setup so mysite.com pointed to your LAN address but now the internal DNS server is gone and the external one points to the public IP.

So either enable NAT lookback in your router if it supports it or setup split DNS so you have a local DNS server for your domain which points to the LAN addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created your new Windows domain with the same domain name as your website? e.g. your website is www.purple.com and your new Windows AD domain is purple.com

As the poster above said, you either need to split your DNS out or create a record on your local DNS server called "www" which has the IP address of your webserver (which you can get by pinging it from a PC which is not on the network that you can't get to your machine from).